# How to handle the fact and dimension table in AWS Glue

Tags: aws-glue

I am new to the AWS Glue.
Can you please provide information to handle the fact and dimension tables from source single table?

"There is a json file from S3 bucket. It has account , balance info and other information.
We haves created two tables ( fact and dimension)
Except amount and balance info need to be feed into dimension table
Amount and balance info along with dimension Reference key to be feed in fact table"

Kindly help me to provide solution or link for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to load fact and then loaded dimension table in different job